# TensorFlow retrain label_image.py (Simple image classification with Inception)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gcloud, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml-engine

For labelling objects,

If I use TensorFlow's label_image.py like:

```
    $ python label_image.py --image=1.jpg --graph=output_inference_graph.pb/frozen_inference_graph.pb --labels=test.txt
```

Error: KeyError: "The name 'final_result:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'final_result', does not exist in the graph."

Reference link:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/label_image.py

Comment: I don't see label_model.py in the TensorFlow repository. Can you include a pointer to the code you are running?

Comment: link pointed out

Comment: Have you retrained inception ?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing output layer parameter which you have use during your training.
Try

```
`bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/label_image \
--graph=/tmp/your_output_graph.pb 
--labels=/tmp/your_output_labels.txt \
--output_layer=final_result:0 \
--image=path_to_your_imahe.jpg`
```

Comment: thats hard coded into application, Yes I am using `--output_layer=final_result:0` parameter